# Getting a single result from a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following piece of code:

```
private void SelectRowData(int wire, int bond, string svid)
{
    var results = from myRow in PPLoadedData.AsEnumerable()
                  where 
                      myRow.Field<Int32>("Wires.OperationOrder") == wire &&
                      myRow.Field<Int32>("Bonds.OperationOrder") == bond
                  select myRow[svid];
}
```

I can see when I debug that results does have my expected single string item. However I cant index or iterate the data by any means that I know of.

What I am looking for is something where i can access the data.

Here is what the debugger says:

> Name:
>   (new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(results)).Items[0]
>
> Value:
>   700.0
>
> Type:
>   object {double}

`PPLoadedData` is a `DataTable`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to return `results` from your method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you expect the query to result in a single item, you should use the `SingleOrDefault` method like so:

```
var result = (from myRow in PPLoadedData.AsEnumerable()
               where myRow.Field<Int32>("Wires.OperationOrder") == wire && 
                     myRow.Field<Int32>("Bonds.OperationOrder") == bond
               select myRow[svid]).SingleOrDefault();
if(result != null)
    // Do stuff with result
```

In general, Linq queries return IEnumerables, which you must iterate over, rather than access by index. However, in the case where you only want a single value, there are several methods to get the value you want. Check out [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

Edit: Be sure to read Eric's answer, which explains when to use which method to get an individual result.

Comment: I do not get an option for FirstOrDefualt(). However iterating over the collection did work as mentioned below. Again though, the result set should only be one value and I feel looping over 1 element is a bad solution. So do you have any other info/example of how I can accomplish this? Thanks again

Edit on your edit. Doesnt a DataTable need the AsEnumerable?

Comment: @SeanP Do you have a `using System.Linq;` statement in your code file?

Comment: I did not. Wow, what an oversight. Thanks. Ive coded my solution!

Comment: @SeanP You're welcome. You are correct about AsEnumerable. I didn't notice that is was a DataTable.

Answer (score 13):

To clarify Jason's answer:

- If the collection can have any number of items, use `FirstOrDefault()`.
- If the collection always has one or more items, use `First()`.
- If the collection always has zero or one items, use `SingleOrDefault()`.
- If the collection always has one item, use `Single()`.

If you use the appropriate method then you get an exception when your invariant is violated, which will help you debug the program.

Answer (score 2):

result is Collection type. you need to iterate over it [Datatable.AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx).   When result is type of `IEneumerable<T>` and other which LINQ returns in collection , you need to iterate like this

```
foreach (var item in results)
{
  //do some thing with item 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This did work but looping over 1 element is not good practice. Do you have anything else you could suggest? thank for you comment by the way.

Comment: You don't have to iterate an IList<T>, as it defines an indexer. I'm also not aware of any LINQ function that returns an IList<T>...